# Eclipse call hierarchy skips calls in undefined #ifdef regions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The "call hierarchy" and "declaration" features in Eclipse CDT omit results that exist in undefined (greyed out) #ifdef regions.

Example:

```
void blah(void) {
#ifndef ABC  
   foo();
#else         //line is greyed out
   bar();     //line is greyed out
#endif        //line is greyed out
}
```

The call hierarchy for foo() will list blah() as a caller; the call hierarchy for bar() will not list blah().

I'm not expecting it to do full resolution of which #define blocks will get compiled, I simply would like it to return all calls/declarations of the function I'm searching for, regardless of the #define blocks that surround it.

Other IDEs such as SlickEdit are able to do this.

Does anyone know of a way to get Eclipse to adopt this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many "bugs" opened on the CDT "Call Hierarchy" feature:

- [Open call hierarchy doesn't work for constructors.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300459)
- [Calls to implicit constructors missing](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=178763)
- [Call graph for constructors does not work for member variables.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=310224)

All of them are linked to the **binding resolution** (also the situation [will improve for implicit constructor calls in CDT7.0](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=248854)).
And since bar() is clearly within an [Unreachable #ifdef block](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=248854), chances are the "binding resolution" will ignore it completely.
Hence the incomplete cal hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2 with PDT 2.x on Windows 7 64Bit Ultimate.

I would expect to see a list of all the places where the method was called from, however I basically only see the declaration of the method itself. Same if I switch to 'callee' hierarchy. Even when the method is called or calls methods in the same file.